# Вывод Map'ы на jsp

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, mvc

не могу вывести ключ и значение Map'ы как хочу
ключ - значение из-за того что в мапе у меня два листа

```
 public Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> task4() {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String genre  = "SELECT book.genre FROM Book book  GROUP BY genre";
    SQLQuery query= session.createSQLQuery(genre);
    List<String>  genreList = query.list();

    String count = "SELECT  COUNT(genre) AS counter FROM book book  GROUP BY genre";
    query= session.createSQLQuery(count);
    List<Integer>  countList = query.list();

    Map<List<String>, List<Integer>> task4List = new Hashtable<List<String>, List<Integer>>();
    task4List.put(genreList,countList);

    return task4List;
}
```

jsp:

```
<c:if test="${!empty task4}">
<table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th width="120">genre</th>
        <th width="120">count</th>


    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${task4}" var="author">
        Key : <c:out value="${author.key}"/>  Value: <c:out value="${author.value}"/> <br />
    </c:forEach>

</table>
```

выводит все в одну строчку из-за листов. Есть ли способ их разделить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
    Map<String, Integer> task4List = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String genre : genreList) {
         task4List.put(genre ,countList.get(genreList.indexOf(genre)));
    }
```

Отобразите

```
<c:forEach items="${task4List}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

тег `<br>` - это следующая строка

Comment: вывод будет выглядеть так  значения 1 листа -  [ , , , , , ] значения 2 листа - [,,,,,,]

Comment: @Jackson750 List<String> использовать в качестве ключа не очень хорошая идея. Я бы посоветовал вам изучить Hibernate. Он сам все данные будет подгружать которые нужны пользователю. В данном примере у вас подход не совсем правильный. Пользователю например нужно количество книг «Война и мир» а вы ему выбрасываете все что у вас в библиотеке есть. Тут вариант постраничность, либо объединить таблицы. А именно колонку COUNT.

Comment: @Jackson750 а представьте теперь если у вас будет 5 000 посетителей и все будут выгружать целую библиотеку с количество в ней книг. Ваш сайт упадет в 3 секунды.

Comment: что значит "изучить Hibernate"? насколько я знаю там нет методов которые заносят все значения запроса по такому примеру как я хочу. Или же есть другая альтернатива?

Comment: @Jackson750 Я не знаю реализацию вашего кода, поэтому не могу подсказать. Сам использую Hibernate, пока все требования наших проектов удовлетворяет.

Comment: Ето вся реализация. здесь доа, сервис вызывает дао а на jsp надо коректно ето вывести.

Comment: @Jackson750 обновил, попробуйте. Этот код должен создавать мапу с именем жанра и количеством книг в нем.

Comment: @Jackson750 но ваша выборка мне все равно не нравится

Comment: просто я как Junior не смог придумать другую реализацию. Просто для такого задания нужно вывести все данные а по другому вывести не получаеться.

Comment: @Jackson750 насколько я понял вам нужно вывести в след формате (жанр - количество книг в жанре), так ведь?

Comment: Именно так и есть

Comment: @Jackson750 ну тогда данный код как раз вам и нужен. А то намутили с листами я вообще ничего не понял зачем это нужно было.

Comment: исправил, у вас вывод не дает значений а так все замечательно

Comment: @Jackson750 с коленки писал просто. Без проверки. Повторите Java Core и Java Collections. Думаю для Junior это основные требования на собеседовании. Минусом не будет для вас однозначно.